# nest start --watch, is continuously compiling without any file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I just started with Nest js, and created a new project using nest cli.

```
nest new project-name
```

Now when I am doing `npm run start:dev` it is continuously compiling without any file changes.
I am getting below message even I am not doing anything.

```
File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
```

I tried the same steps on different machine then it works fine. Any suggestions what can be the issue with the system? I am facing issue on a window machine.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel   Facing issue on Windows 10

Comment: try reinstalling globally the cli socket (respectively create a new project after), also you can reinstall your IDE.

Comment: @choco Tried reinstalling @nest/cli, and then new project but same issue.

Comment: Using yarn instead of npm helps to resolve the issue.